# VB.NET Opening A File From Form

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the following the code to open a file that resides elsewhere on the computer:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(PathToOpen)
```

Where `PathToOpen` is the full address to the file I wish to open. This appears to work as intended for any file type that has an application installed that can open the file.

Whilst this works OK, if the file is on a networked drive, I want my VB.Net code to check if the file is currently in use, if so display a message. Currently what happens is if a second user tries to open the file, it opens read-only (a word file for example) which is handled outside of my application. I want to intercept before the file is opened and stop the process there.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Try to open the file with FileShare.None.  If that doesn't cause an exception then you have decent odds that the app you start won't have a problem either.  It can never be 100% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking if it's possible to monitor files on a system that doesn't even belong to you ?

Word does know about a file already in use because it creates a hidden file next to the one you open. if there is already a hidden file, it means the file is already in use.

Other applications use different ways of knowing if a file they can use is already opened somewhere else.

In order to do what you want to do, you need to know how all the applications handle this problem...

A possible solution would be for you to create a small hidden file next to the file the user wants to open (just like MS Word does). Only problem, you need to destroy the file when it's closed by the user, and you have no way of knowing that...